# Upload (not read) a .xlsx file from HTML and send it (any way) to a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an .xlsx file and a html file with an < input type="file">. I just need upload it and send it to a php file (with js or any other way).

The php file expects an .xlsx file (for this reason I dont parse the .xlsx.) if I load it direct in the php file, works perfectly but I need to upload through an user interface, in this case an html view.

Regards.

**Update:**

Now the .html looks like this:

```
<div class="MainContainerPrice">
    <form action="php/excel_to_mysql.php" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="excel" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

And the .php looks like this:

```
<?php 

  include 'simplexlsx.class.php';
  $file = $_FILES['excel'];
  $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX('pricesExcel.xlsx'); //the file directly uploaded that I need to send from html.
  ...

?>
```

But now I have the next error:

Undefined index: excel in ...\excel_to_mysql.php on line 2.

Why doesn't recognize the name?

Comment: `input`s must be in `form method="post"` container. Check `$_FILES` on the `php` side.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated the code, but looks like doesn't recognize the name, what I'm doing wrong? Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a bit of tweaking in the html and in the PHP part

```
<div class="MainContainerPrice">
    <form action="php/excel_to_mysql.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="excel" accept="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Note the `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. That's needed to actually send the file.

The in the PHP file

```
<?php 

  include 'simplexlsx.class.php';
  $file = $_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'];
  $xlsx = new SimpleXLSX($file); //the file directly uploaded that I need to send from html.
  ...

?>
```

`$_FILES['excel']['tmp_name']` contains the full path to the uploaded file, note that you can't rely on the name having the '.xlsx' extension, cause the file gets a random name for security purposes.

I *strongly* suggest you to use the file from within the temporary directory, and to delete it after use.

If the `SimpleXLSX`class needs the '.xlsx' extension to work properly, you can try to add it to the temp file

```
rename($_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['excel']['tmp_name'].'.xlsx');
```